# regex match multiple unordered capture groups

Tags: regex, nginx

I've seen a few explanations online but I dont fully understand them.
I have a uri that is unordered, and can also have optional parameters, which may or may not be part of the uri when called.
Something of the form

`/getthis?servicename=aservice&userid=123555712345&something=value&anotherthing=novalue`
or

`/getthis?servicename=aservice&userid=123555712345`

The parameters `servicename` and `userid` will always be there, but `something` (and other parameters/values) may or may be added to the uri or not.

I've tried to use named groups to capture each parameter section of interest, and to deal with appearing or not appearing url parameters, by doing this:

`^(?<a>servicename=.*)&(?<b>userid=(123(555|666|777|...)\d+))(?<c>\&?.*)$`

(userid has groups of digits that need to be matched, and this matching affects how servicename's value will be modified.)

but I don't know how to ensure that if the capture groups appear in any order, they will be parsed.
Please can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You can use separate regexes to match each part of the string you want. If you do not know the exact positioning of the params, it is the most convenient approach.

Comment: Please can you elaborate further? I'm trying to do this on single lines with ngnix maps.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is probably not the best solution for your situation. If you can use a url library in your language of interest, that would be easiest, but otherwise you would be better off splitting the URL at `&`, then breaking the resulting parameters at `=` to get the pairs. Then process the parameter key/values.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant use an url library. I have to do this in nginx.